# Github OAuth in Openshift

Tags: github, oauth, openshift

We have an Openshift 4.13 cluster and have configured Github as the OAuth provider. We've restricted access to two teams from Github and have confirmed that only the users in those teams can log in.

Is there a way to map the two teams from GitHub to separate groups or roles in Openshift so we can grant them different permissions?

The only thing I have found so far is that using something like `oc adm policy add-role-to-group <ROLE NAME> system:authenticated` would give the same permissions to every logged in user. What I'd really like to do is add each Github team to a group and grant permissions to that group. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you make clear, OAuth or OAuth2?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own group using `oc adm groups new` command (Please see help with your command line) and adding users to the group. Usually, you need to map users to groups manually.

Here is another way to create group.
If you have groups in github, you can use group sync operator to sync groups in Github to OpenShift.

This is provided by Red Hat however, not supported. But, I think it could be useful to manage your groups in OpenShift.

https://github.com/redhat-cop/group-sync-operator